# How to call multiple user variables - iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

First off, I'm a noob at iPhone application development, so forgive me if I don't get it right away.

I have a simple question concerning how to call multiple variables in a sentence-style text with other words in between the variables.

I'm teaching myself iPhone application development, so I'm basing this code off the instructions by Apple entitled "Your First iOS App" and tweaking the code to learn it better.

The basic layout of the app is two text fields labeled "Name" and "Occupation". Below that is a text area (label) and a button for submitting the text field information. Once the user inputs and submits their Name and Occupation, the application should place those variables into the sentence: "Hello, my name is [Name], and I'm a [Occupation]." and display the sentence in the text area (label).

This is what I have so far:

```
- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

self.userName = self.textField.text;

NSString *nameString = self.userName;
if ([nameString length] == 0) {
    nameString = @"Name";
}
    NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, my name is %@,", nameString];
self.label.text = greeting;

self.userOccupation = self.textField.text;

NSString *occupationString = self.userOccupation;
if ([occupationString length] == 0) {
    occupationString = @"Occupation";
}
NSString *description = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" and I'm a %@.", occupationString];
self.label.text = description;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
if (theTextField == self.textField) {
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
return YES;
}
@end
```

When running the app and submitting the name "John" and the occupation "developer", the output sentence does not include the "Hello, my name is John," output, only the "and I'm a developer."

How do I get and call the variables in such a way that each variable is displayed in its desired place in the sentence so that it reads "Hello, my name is John, and I'm a developer." in one interrupted sentence?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same textfield to obtain Name and occupation? That's odd.

Anyway, as you are also using the same label to display the sentence, you are replacing the "Hello, my name is John" by  "and I'm a developer." with this lines:

```
NSString *description = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" and I'm a %@.", occupationString];
self.label.text = description;
```

Replace the last line "self.label.text = description;" with the line suggested by atbebtg and you should get the desired result.

```
self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",greeting, description];
```

By the way, if you aren't using ARC, remember to release all you variables created with alloc.

Comment: Thanks! That helped, but I still have a problem.

I have two different textFields, one for Name and another for Occupation, but I'm having difficulty calling them both in the output sentence. The Name variable is called userName and Occupation is userOccupation on the textFields.

When I run the app with the modification you suggested, it brings up "Hello, my name is developer, and I'm a developer." It leaves John out completely.

Comment: what's the difficult? if you have two textfields, use something like this: self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, my name is %@ and I'm a %@", nameTextField.text, occupationTextField.text];

Answer (score 0):

You overwritten the value of self.label.text with description that's why you only see the description value being displayed.

replace this line

```
self.label.text = description;
```

with

```
self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",greeting, description];
```

my syntax might be a little bit off.